# Run cron now without changing its settings

Tags: cron

I have a job scheduled by cron: popping emails from server every hour.

But sometimes I don't want to wait for 60 minutes to check my emails. To do it, I use a script which run the same command I have in crontab. It is essentially as running the cron before it was scheduled tor run. Is it possible to run cron at particular time without changing it's settings?

Comment: I'm not following -- do you mind adding more information, perhaps `crontab -l` output?

Comment: I have tried to make it clearer. Say my cron is scheduled to run at 12:20 but right now its 12.00. Can it execute crontab right now at 12.00?

Comment: You can always duplicate the crontab entry with a different time but why don't you just manually execute the command when you need it?

Comment: That's I am doing it now. I was wondering if there is any command to start cron at your whim any time your like, overriding its default behaviour!

Comment: AFAIK the whole purpose of `cron` is running scheduled, unattended tasks, seems that's not what you need in the scenario you describe.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following:

```
at now /cron/monthly_save
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I have read man page of at. It looks like a potential answer. But how can I run commands specified in cron?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by using the tool `anacron`, in addition to `cron`. Forcing execution of a job then becomes as easy as:

```
anacron -f <your jobname>
```